# Simple question about form formatting in Django

Tags: django, forms, format, customization

I'd like to produce a form that lets users input a list of grocery items. Each item is defined by a name, amount, and category. I'm currently doing this using formsets. Here's the code from which I create a formset instance in my views.py file:

```
class InputForm(forms.Form): 
    item = forms.CharField() 
    amount = forms.CharField() 
    category = forms.CharField()
```

But this produces an output that looks like this:

```
Item: 
Amount:
Category:
Item: 
Amount:
Category:
```

How can I format the output so that the "item, amount, category" sequence becomes horizontal?

```
Item: [room for user input]  Amount: [user input]  Category: [user selection]
Item: [room for user input]  Amount: [user input]  Category: [user selection]
```

Do I have to work within the template, or can I do something within my forms.py file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options:

(1) Iterate over the formset in your template, and use your template to layout the forms; or

(2) Override the layout methods in Form to alter the html layout that is generated.

I prefer (2), but plenty of people prefer (1). The advantage of (2) is that you can reuse that layout code if you break it out into a mixin. (I have actually achieved this with monkey-patching, but that is unnecessary).